# Snowflake task to run the job every 2nd day of month (working day)

Tags: cron, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scheduler

Snowflake task to be executed on every 2nd day of month (working day)and i need the Cron parameters for this.

Comment: What have you tried from [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#optional-parameters) ?

Comment: not to run on SAT/SUN if the 2nd  day of the months falls....

Comment: I don't think that's possible as Tasks schedules mimic Unix cron schedules which also can't satisfy that requirement without any extra scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific cron combination for this, but you could define:

- A cron combination that runs every day.
- A stored procedure that checks the rules you defined ("today is the second day of the month, and today is not a Sat/Sun"), before running the rest of the stored procedure.

Have the Snowflake task call said stored procedure with said cron combination.